# Client does not support authentication protocol

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I am deploying my app on aws ec2 and while runing my app by node app.js it gives the above mentioned error and upon changing privileges following prompt occurs and nothing happens
[image]

Comment: plz click enter image description here to see the problem

Comment: please add the text as text and not as image

Comment: i have added ss of mysql server so that it is more understandable

Comment: End the `ALTER USER ....` statement with a `;` on the mysql prompt to indicate the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your ec2 instance and the database server can ping each other.

Comment: This isn't the answer. The `alter user` was never executed, so nothing changed. The error in the title occurred because there was a connection.